# I receive "the application has stopped unexpectedly",While minSdkVersion is equal to 8

Tags: android

I created a program that draws a simple rectangle. It compiles without any problems. When I install the **apk** file on the device it installs successfully, but after a while, I receive the following alert message.

> I receive "the application has stopped unexpectedly", While
>   minSdkVersion is equal to 8

I changed the  **minSdkVersion** equal to 8, but the problem persists.

**Does anybody know have I can solve this problem?**

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Rr rec;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceView){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceView);
    setContentView(rec);
    }
}
```

**Rr.java**

```
public class Rr extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Rr (Context context){
     super(context);
 }

   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawRect(10,10,100,155,paint);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examplee.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        >
<activity

android:name="MainActivity"

android:label="@string/app_name" >

<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>

</activity>
        </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: post your crash logs

Comment: Use `adb logcat` or the equivalent built into your IDE to find out what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Where are you initializing 'Rr rec' ? Also it is good practice to use LogCat to see what exactly caused the application to stop.